# Error 404 en la función logout de Ion Auth con Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Pues eso, al llamar a esta función para redirigirme al Login de nuevo me manda un error 404 de página no localizada, el caso es que he seguido los mismos pasos que seguí para otra aplicación que hice y que no me dio problemas ¿alguna idea?

**Link**

```
<li>
                            <a href="<?= base_url('auth/logout') ?>">Salir</a>
                        </li>
```

**Función logout de Ion Auth**

```
// log the user out
    public function logout() {
        $this->data['title'] = "Logout";

        // log the user out
        $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();

        // redirect them to the login page
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
        redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
    }
```

**Base_url**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/herba/';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para corregirlo he cambiado la url de `<li>
                            <a href="<?= base_url('auth/logout') ?>">Salir</a>
                        </li>` 
a

`<li>
                            <a href="<?= base_url('index.php/auth/logout') ?>">Salir</a>
                        </li>`